# What invertible matrices $A$ satisfy $A^T C A = C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C$ be an invertible, symmetric, pos-def matrix. These properties might not be very relevant to my question, but in the application I have in mind, $C$ is a full rank correlation matrix.

What invertible square matrices $A$ satisfy $A^T C A = C$?

Comment: I think there can be many such matrices, one of them being $I$.

Comment: @Letsintegreat Yes, but can we find them (besides the trivial $I$)? Or is there some characterization that sheds some light on the requirements on $A$?

Comment: Any orthogonal matrix $A$, for example, if $C=I$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What about general $C$?

Comment: In principle, a similar answer for general invertible $C$. There is a big class of matrices, namely coming from isometries, which satisfy this equation.

Answer (score 1):

See $C$ as the matrix, in the canonical basis, of a quadratic form $q$. Then the matrices $A$ you are looking for are exactly the matrices of isometries w.r.t $q$, i.e.
$$\lbrace A \text{ such that } A^TCA=C \rbrace = O(q)$$

Indeed, let $\varphi$ be the bilinear form associated to $q$. Then for any endomorphism $u$ whose matrix in the canonical basis is $A$, it is easy to see that the matrix of the bilinear form $\varphi(u(.),u(.))$ is exactly $A^TCA$. So $A^TCA=A$ means exactly that $\varphi(u(.),u(.))=\varphi(.,.)$, i.e. that $u$ is an isometry for the bilinear form $\varphi$ (or equivalently for the quadratic form $q$).

For example, if $C$ is the identity matrix, then you can see it as the matrix of the quadratic form given by the usual dot product ; then you get all the isometries (in the usual sense, i.e. w.r.t. the usual norm). This general to any quadratic form as I explained.